# Bootstrap - How can I remove the extra space from the bottom of this bootstrap card?

Tags: html, css, jinja2, bootstrap-5

So I was making a blog app, but this is annoying me, the problem is that instead of resizing to only occupy the space as large as the size of the card, but it occupying the whole column

[image]

This is my code (Jinja2)

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block title %}
Blogs - DevExplorer
{% endblock title %}

{% block content %}
<div class="container">
    <div class="row no-gutters">
        <div class="text-center">
            <a href="{{ url_for('new_post') }}">
                <button class="btn btn-primary btn-primary btn-lg rainbow-button">Post A New Blog</button>
            </a>

            <br><br><br>
        </div>

        <!-- Displaying the posts, if the database if empty telling the user to post a post -->
        {% if posts.items != [] %}
            {% for i in posts.items %}
                <!-- Displaying the posts if exists -->
                {% if i.thumbnail %}
                <a href="{{ url_for('post_detail', primary_key=i.id) }}" class="col-auto" style="text-decoration: none; color: white;">
                    <div class="col-auto">
                        <div class="card cards" style="box-shadow: 1px 1px 30px black; border: none; width: 612px;">
                            <div class="card-body" style="margin: 0; padding: 0;">
                                <img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='profile_pics/' ~ i.author.profile_picture) }}" alt="DP" width="32"
                                    height="32">&ensp;{{ i.author.username }}
                            </div>

                            <br>

                            <span class="text-muted" style="margin-bottom: 10px;">Posted On: {{ i.date_posted.date() }}</span>
                            <img src="{{ i.thumbnail }}" alt="Image Support" style="border-radius: 25px;">

                            <br>

                            <h5 class="card-title" style="font-weight: 600;">
                                {{ i.title }}
                            </h5>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </a>
                {% else %}
                <a href="{{ url_for('post_detail', primary_key=i.id) }}" class="col-auto" style="text-decoration: none; color: white;">
                    <div class="col-auto">
                        <div class="card cards" style="box-shadow: 1px 1px 30px black; border: none; width: 612px;">
                            <div class="card-body" style="margin: 0; padding: 0;">
                                <img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='profile_pics/' ~ i.author.profile_picture) }}" alt="DP"
                                    width="32" height="32">&ensp;{{ i.author.username }}
                            </div>
                
                            <br>
                
                            <span class="text-muted" style="margin-bottom: 10px;">Posted On: {{ i.date_posted.date() }}</span>
                
                            <br>
                
                            <h5 class="card-title" style="font-weight: 600;">
                                {{ i.title }}
                            </h5>

                            <p class="elipsis" style="height: 17rem;">
                                {{ i.content }}
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </a>
                {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}
        {% else %}
            <!-- Messaging the user that no posts exists -->
            <h1 style="font-weight: bolder; text-align: center;">No Posts Yet! Be the first to post one!</h1>
        {% endif %}
    </div>

    <!-- Pagination -->
    {% for page_num in posts.iter_pages(left_edge=1, right_edge=1, left_current=1, right_current=2) %}
        {% if page_num %}
            {% if posts.page == page_num %}
                <a class="btn btn-info" style="margin: 5px;" href="{{ url_for('list_posts', page=page_num) }}">{{ page_num }}</a>
            {% else %}
                <a class="btn btn-outline-info" style="margin: 5px;" href="{{ url_for('list_posts', page=page_num) }}">{{ page_num }}</a>
            {% endif %}

        {% else %}
            ...
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}

</div>
<br><br>

{% endblock content %}
```

I did try using `col-auto` but It still doesn't work, and distorts the layout of the page
any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What happening here is that the card is adapting the height of the card which is on his side. So if you want cards to be not the same height on the same axis then you can use a thing called Masonry. It will allow you to achieve the results that you want.

Include this js file in your document

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/masonry-layout@4/dist/masonry.pkgd.min.js"></script>
```

and adding `data-masonry='{"percentPosition": true }'` to the `.row` wrapper.

#### See the code in action.

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/masonry-layout@4/dist/masonry.pkgd.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row" data-masonry="{&quot;percentPosition&quot;: true }" style="position: relative; height: 1953.6px;">
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-4 mb-4" style="position: absolute; left: 0%; top: 0px;">
      <div class="card">
        <svg class="bd-placeholder-img card-img-top" width="100%" height="200" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" role="img" aria-label="Placeholder: Image cap" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" focusable="false"><title>Placeholder</title><rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#868e96"></rect><text x="50%" y="50%" fill="#dee2e6" dy=".3em">Image cap</text></svg>

        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title">Card title that wraps to a new line</h5>
          <p class="card-text">This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-4 mb-4" style="position: absolute; left: 0%; top: 410px;">
      <div class="card p-3">
        <figure class="p-3 mb-0">
          <blockquote class="blockquote">
            <p>A well-known quote, contained in a blockquote element.</p>
          </blockquote>
          <figcaption class="blockquote-footer mb-0 text-muted">
            Someone famous in <cite title="Source Title">Source Title</cite>
          </figcaption>
        </figure>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-4 mb-4" style="position: absolute; left: 0%; top: 609.6px;">
      <div class="card">
        <svg class="bd-placeholder-img card-img-top" width="100%" height="200" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" role="img" aria-label="Placeholder: Image cap" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" focusable="false"><title>Placeholder</title><rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#868e96"></rect><text x="50%" y="50%" fill="#dee2e6" dy=".3em">Image cap</text></svg>

        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
          <p class="card-text">This card has supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
          <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-4 mb-4" style="position: absolute; left: 0%; top: 987.6px;">
      <div class="card bg-primary text-white text-center p-3">
        <figure class="mb-0">
          <blockquote class="blockquote">
            <p>A well-known quote, contained in a blockquote element.</p>
          </blockquote>
          <figcaption class="blockquote-footer mb-0 text-white">
            Someone famous in <cite title="Source Title">Source Title</cite>
          </figcaption>
        </figure>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-4 mb-4" style="position: absolute; left: 0%; top: 1125.6px;">
      <div class="card text-center">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
          <p class="card-text">This card has a regular title and short paragraph of text below it.</p>
          <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-4 mb-4" style="position: absolute; left: 0%; top: 1303.6px;">
      <div class="card">
        <svg class="bd-placeholder-img card-img" width="100%" height="260" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" role="img" aria-label="Placeholder: Card image" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" focusable="false"><title>Placeholder</title><rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#868e96"></rect><text x="50%" y="50%" fill="#dee2e6" dy=".3em">Card image</text></svg>

      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-4 mb-4" style="position: absolute; left: 0%; top: 1589.6px;">
      <div class="card p-3 text-end">
        <figure class="mb-0">
          <blockquote class="blockquote">
            <p>A well-known quote, contained in a blockquote element.</p>
          </blockquote>
          <figcaption class="blockquote-footer mb-0 text-muted">
            Someone famous in <cite title="Source Title">Source Title</cite>
          </figcaption>
        </figure>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-4 mb-4" style="position: absolute; left: 0%; top: 1727.6px;">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
          <p class="card-text">This is another card with title and supporting text below. This card has some additional content to make it slightly taller overall.</p>
          <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```